# Mobile Safari uses Webkit1/Webkit2?

Tags: ios, webkit, mobile-safari, mobile-webkit

I am researching a bit about Mobile safari and have searched the web for any information about the process model being used.

Webkit1 was a single process framework and with Webkit2 the chromium style multi-process model was introduced in Webkit. But no where is there a mention of Mobile Safari using the same.

Is there anyway to detect which Webkit(1/2) is being used in the latest Mobile Safari? Is there any changelog of the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure in my answer, but there is a private framework called WebKit2.framework in iOS7. You can check it [here](https://github.com/EthanArbuckle/IOS-7-Headers/tree/master/PrivateFrameworks).

So, it's quite possible, that Safari uses WebKit2.

Comment: So by private, you mean the unpublished framework or a custom made by a third party developer? Thanks for the link though.

Comment: by private I mean those frameworks, which are not available for use by developers, but they exist in iOS. You can use these frameworks only if u r developing an app for the jailbroken device.